# oocharts invalid filter parameters after array is converted to string

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I've been having trouble setting a dynamic filter for oocharts.

I've looped through some things and have created an array (scenefilters) which I've joined to make a string. I've then tried to use this as a filter, which returns the error:

*JSONP.callbacks.request_63 && JSONP.callbacks.request_63({"error":"Invalid param {filters}: Filter string is not in valid format"});*

Now if I console.log the variable 'locationfilter2' and copy and paste it directly into the filter, it works fine - but it doesn't work just with the variable. Do I need to do something else to the variable to make sure it's a string?

```
    var locationfilter = scenefilters.join(",");
    var locationfilter2 = '"'+ locationfilter +'"';

    var visits = new oo.Metric("54190402", "12m");                  
    visits.setMetric("ga:visits");
visits.query.setFilter(locationfilter2);                                
    visits.draw(timeline);
```

**EDIT**

I've tried outputting the variable to a textfield and copying it from there, same thing. The output is "ga:pagePath=~s101$,ga:pagePath=~s102$,ga:pagePath=~s103$,ga:pagePath=~s104$,ga:pagePath=~s105$,ga:pagePath=~s106$,ga:pagePath=~s107$,ga:pagePath=~s108$,ga:pagePath=~s109$,ga:pagePath=~s110$,ga:pagePath=~s111$,ga:pagePath=~s112$,ga:pagePath=~s113$,ga:pagePath=~s114$,ga:pagePath=~s115$,ga:pagePath=~s116$,ga:pagePath=~s117$,ga:pagePath=~s118$,ga:pagePath=~s119$,ga:pagePath=~s293$,ga:pagePath=~s301$"

And if I copy this directly into the filter, i.e. visits.query.setFilter("ga:pagePath=~s101$,ga:pagePath=~s102$,ga:pagePath=~s103$,ga:pagePath=~s104$,ga:pagePath=~s105$,ga:pagePath=~s106$,ga:pagePath=~s107$,ga:pagePath=~s108$,ga:pagePath=~s109$,ga:pagePath=~s110$,ga:pagePath=~s111$,ga:pagePath=~s112$,ga:pagePath=~s113$,ga:pagePath=~s114$,ga:pagePath=~s115$,ga:pagePath=~s116$,ga:pagePath=~s117$,ga:pagePath=~s118$,ga:pagePath=~s119$,ga:pagePath=~s293$,ga:pagePath=~s301$");

It works well. But if I use the variable I get the error. Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK stupid one. Removed the ""s and it works fine.